# Implementing ReCaptcha V3 with AWS Lambda within VPC

Tags: aws-lambda, recaptcha

For our new startup we have implemented our new marketing site on AWS.

We are using Amazon CloudFront as our CDN, AWS S3 for website hosting and AWS Lambda for our sign up API writing to our AWS RDS database. Cloudfront routes to the Lambda function through API gateway.

The Lambda function operates within the VPC so it can write to Amazon RDS.

We want to implement the server side ReCaptcha V3 check within our Lambda function but as Lambdas within a VPC do not have external internet access, the call to validate with Google times out.

I've read we can overcome this with setting up a NAT gateway but running a gateway continuously is a cost we would like to defer for the moment if we can.

I have thought of the following options:

1. Create a non vpc lambda function to validate the ReCaptcha token. Call this from the VPC lambda function. Will this work?
2. As we are using CloudFront, create a Lambda@Edge function to validate the ReCaptcha token. If the validation passes, route to the VPC lambda function as normal. If the validation fails, return a response directly error to the client.
3. Use SES. Ideally we wanted a synchronous response (i.e. any errors are responded to the client). This would be a bit more work but my only query would be can you write to a SES queue from a non VPC lambda function?

Any pointers or any other options would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't add a NAT Gateway to give your VPC Lambda function access to the Internet?

Comment: Just costs as we our bootstrapping at the moment and only small amounts of traffic will be going through Lambda. Seems others have this issue too and defeats the object of serverless https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=234959

Comment: Option #1 won't work, because a Lambda function running in a VPC without a NAT gateway giving it Internet access won't be able to access the AWS API to invoke another Lambda function either. Option 2 sounds like the best user experience for the cheapest cost to me.

Comment: Thanks that’s what I thought, I’ll implement but I think I have to do it in node!